# Will a Stored Proc be consider compiled if it does not have an entry in cache?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working on SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a stored proc `Rpt_RegionReport`. It has been run at least once so I can say it is **compiled**. It has an entry in cache which I can see in `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans`.

Now I delete it from the cache using its `plan_handle` and calling `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` and passing its `plan_handle` to it. I confirm that it has no entry in cache anymore.

Now, 
do you think this stored proc is still consider **compiled** although it does not have an entry in cache?
OR 
do you think this stored proc is now consider **not compiled** since it does not have an entry in cache?

I am trying to figure when SQL Server consider a stored proc as **not compiled** and **compiled**.

Thanks

Comment: Are you just curious or are you trying to figure something else out?

Comment: Mostly curious; basically needs to explain to the manager the difference between **compiled** and **not compiled** in this case

Comment: Please see my update as I tried to better address the definition of "compiled".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say "not compiled" if it doesn't have an entry in the Plan Cache. The next time it is called it should need to be parsed and compiled.

And just to be clear, plans do not stay cached forever. The cache is cleared when SQL Server service is restarted, when you call DBCC FREEPROCCACHE, and if the system needs to add more plans and is running out of space in the plan cache, it will start removing older plans that have not been used in a while.

**EDIT:**
Also, it would help to clarify the term "compiled", as it is not the same thing as C# / C++ / VB.NET / F# being compiled into an EXE or DLL. Take a look at the MSDN page for [sys.dm_exec_cached_plans](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187404.aspx). We are talking about "query plans" here, and those plans can be for a variety of different object types, including Ad Hoc queries. Do not get caught up on the name of `FREEPROCCACHE` thinking that you are really dealing with the procedure itself. The term "PROC" in "FREE**PROC**CACHE" is probably from an older version of SQL Server (2000 or earlier) when the cache probably only contained plans for stored procedures.

And, since you are needing to explain this to your manager, it should be pointed out that the "query plan" that is "compiled" is "how" SQL Server will perform the query. It is the types of JOINs, when certain things are done, such as executing functions and sorting, etc. There are many, many ways to go about performing each query and the plan cache allows SQL Server to potentially skip the amount of time it takes to calculate (i.e. "compile") those variations when trying to find the best method, by reusing the answer it came up with last time (whether it was a good answer or even a bad answer).

Answer (score 1):

> do you think this stored proc is still consider compiled although it
>   does not have an entry in cache?

AFAIK, you get an entry in `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans` only when the stored procedure runs for first time and not just after compiling it. Also, the compilation of the procedure happens on demand. For example, if you just created the procedure then it may not be compiled yet but when you run it for first time it gets compiled and the compiled plan is cached for re-use.

So, **No** it's not compiled anymore. Running `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` will invalidate all stored procedure plans that the optimizer has cached in memory and force `SQL Server` to compile and generate new plans the next time those procedures are run. Run it again and it will re-generate and cache the plan.

You can use the `WITH RECOMPILE` option in your procedure body if you want to generate a new plan and don't want to re-use the cached plan.

Comment: so basically it is possible to compile a stored proc and yet don't have an execution plan? if yes then how?

Comment: @srh, see my edit in answer. I corrected the answer; in single sentence `No, the procedure is not compiled anymore `.